# How to use an exisiting OpenPGP key from Launchpad

Tags: launchpad, gnupg, openpgp

I want `gpg` to use my existing active OpenPGP key from Launchpad without having to generate and import a new key.

---

`$ gpg --list-keys` returns nothing.

Btw I'm trying to sign the Code of Conduct

```
$ gpg --clearsign UbuntuCodeofConduct-2.0.txt 
gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
gpg: UbuntuCodeofConduct-2.0.txt: clearsign failed: secret key not available
```

Comment: You somehow need to export your keys from launchpad and then import them into your keyrings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sign the code of conduct, you need to have the **secret** key of the key you're signing it with. Launchpad (and other key servers) only store the **public** key. Therefore, if you don't have the secret key of the key that's registered with your account on Launchpad, you'll need to generate a new key.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue, after some research and struggle I came out with this:

Instead of: `$ gpg --list-keys` and `$ gpg --clearsign UbuntuCodeofConduct-2.0.txt`,

use: `$ gpg2 --list-keys` and `$ gpg2 --clearsign UbuntuCodeofConduct-2.0.txt`.

Also, in order to see your secret key, use `gpg2 --list-secret-keys`. (Just to see that there exists)

Hope it helps!